# Does the exchange rate in a vault contract stay flat from one depositor to the next if the underlying tokens have not increased in between deposits?

Tags: solidity

I am reviewing a vault contract where people submit an underlying token and receive vault shares. The amount of underlying tokens is expected to gain value but it does so sporadically, so it is possible for the amount of underlying tokens in the vault to be the same for awhile across multiple deposits.

What I am trying to figure out is, if the total amount of underlying token does stay the same after a deposit is made all the way until another deposit is made, the exchange rate for the two deposits is the same. I think it is but I am doubting myself